# Object becoming null outside return statements

Tags: java

this may be a simple problem, but I've looked for an answer and I'm just not finding it anywhere. I'm trying to use a method to check if an inputted answer is correct compared to the actual answer. The actual answer is defined by a setter, and the getter works also. But in the method where it's compared it becomes null. This isn't a question about why comparing them returns null, but why correctAnswer is null in the first place. I'm confused because getCorrectAnswer() works as intended.

Here is the code:

public class MultipleChoiceQuestion implements Question
{

```
String question;
String correctAnswer;

public String getQuestion() 
{
    return question;
}

public boolean isCorrectAnswer(String answer) 
{
    if (answer != correctAnswer)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public String getCorrectAnswer() 
{
    return correctAnswer;
}

public void setQuestion(String questionText){
    question = questionText;
}

public void setAnswer(String answer){
    correctAnswer = answer;
}
```

}

"answer != correctAnswer" doesn't work because correctAnswer is null in that method.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: See also [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: I looked in the compare strings thread but I couldn't find any solutions to my problem.

Comment: I wasn't offering an answer.

Comment: You aren't setting the value

Comment: Oh, sorry, I would set it outside the class somewhere else, getCorrectAnswer works fine in that case

Comment: There's nothing in the code you shared that would cause that. Again, we can't help without a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t use equality for classes unless you want to check that two are perfectly identical, that is, the same object. You should use `Object.equals`. So `answer.equals(correctAnswer)` is more correct. Also, are you sure that the setter was called first?

Comment: I tried .equals and changing the order but that didn't seem to do anything. Calling getcorrectanswer works fine